# CSS not loaded || Spring

Tags: java, html, css, spring

After logging in on my page, spring redirects me to my main site using the following controller:

```
//Login Success    
@GetMapping("/login-success")
public ModelAndView loginSuccess() {
    return new ModelAndView("/cont/home.html");
}
```

the URL looks like:

http://localhost:8080/login-success

It is the HTML structure of home.html but the CSS is not loaded.
If I navigate to http://localhost:8080/cont/home.html it is styled.

Thanks for the help. :)

Comment: Where is your css located?

Comment: main/resources/static/styles
and html in 
main/resources/static

Comment: What is 'cont' in the URL?

Comment: @AtulDwivedi Cont is just a sub-folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this below

```
return new ModelAndView("/CONTEXT_PATH/cont/home.html");
```

**OR**

```
response.sendRedirect("/cont/home.html");
return;
```

specify with context path so that the page will be loaded

Comment: I have just tried it with return new RedicectView("/cont/home.html") and it works too.

Should i specify the CONTEXT_PATH or just write it there? CAuse like that it says "No message available"..

Comment: Yep. It does.

But i have similar problems with other things:

Comment: If I go to my logout page (exact same as login just with a changed headline),
I cant login again - shows a POST Error.
Also if i wanna login on my "/ " path I get a POST Error. I HAVE to go to ../login

Comment: And how can I use response?
If I add HttpServletResponse in my Controller it shows me an unreported Exception..

Comment: surround with try catch

Comment: Okay, I'll try it tomorrow. Thanks!

Comment: Using return value "void" instead of "ModelAndView", the sendredirect doesn't work. Giving me an error.

Comment: I think you try this article https://www.baeldung.com/spring-redirect-and-forward

Comment: Okay, but my method with RedirectView is also valid?